# Flutter - How to convert "Switch" to "raised button" ( Push-Notifications )?

Tags: flutter, switch-statement

I would like to convert a "switch" to a "raised button" or similar, and get the corresponding function...

```
                      **Switch(
                        onChanged: (bool enabled) {
                          setState(() {
                            _notificationsEnabled = enabled;
                            _updateNotifications(enabled);
                          });
                        },
                        value: _notificationsEnabled,
                      ),**
```

Excerpt from the total code :

```
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0, bottom: 5.0, right: 5.0, left: 5.0),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border(
                          bottom: BorderSide(
                              color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.13)
                          )
                      )
                  ),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text('PUSH-BENACHRICHTIGUNGEN AKTIVIEREN', style: TextStyle(color: isDark ? Colors.cyanAccent : Color(0xFF000000), fontFamily: "Storopia", fontSize: 13.0)),
                      **Switch(
                        onChanged: (bool enabled) {
                          setState(() {
                            _notificationsEnabled = enabled;
                            _updateNotifications(enabled);
                          });
                        },
                        value: _notificationsEnabled,
                      ),**
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
```

[pictorial representation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0i8iV.jpg)

The goal is to create a "raised button" which lights up green when push notifications are activated and red when they are deactivated instead of the switch. I am not sure if there is a simple solution for this, but I hope that someone has an easy solution since I am a newbie. I was helped here before and it was super easy and quick, I was totally surprised and think it's great that there is such an active community here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dart
**Switch(
                        onChanged: (bool enabled) {
                          setState(() {
                            _notificationsEnabled = enabled;
                            _updateNotifications(enabled);
                          });
                        },
                        value: _notificationsEnabled,
                      ),**
```

You can use a ternary:

```dart
// Below your stateful widget class
bool _enabled = false;

// [...]

RaisedButton(
      color: _enabled ? Colors.green : Colors.red,
      onPressed: () {
        setState(() {
          _enabled = !_enabled;
          _updateNotifications(_enabled);
        });
      },
      child: Text(_enabled? "On" : "Off")),
```

Comment: thank you very much   that seems to work, but I'm not sure if the function works correctly ...