# Flutter - How to convert “FlatButton” to "RaisedButton" ( Switch Dark / Light Theme ) ? + TextStyle

Tags: flutter

Anybody knows how to convert this 2 dark / light theme "flatbutton" to one "raisedbutton" to switch the dark and light theme ?

Dark / light theme code :

```
                  child: FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Magazin.of(context).setBrightness(Brightness.dark);
                    },
                    child: Text('DARK MODE', style: TextStyle(color: isDark ? Colors.black : Colors.white, fontFamily: "SampleFont", fontSize: 13.0)),
                  ),


                  child: FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Magazin.of(context).setBrightness(Brightness.light);
                    },

                    child: Text('LIGHT MODE', style: TextStyle(color: isDark ? Colors.black : Colors.white, fontFamily: "SampleFont", fontSize: 13.0)),
```

Raisedbutton sample code :

( [Flutter - How to convert "Switch" to "raised button" ( Push-Notifications )?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66287855/flutter-how-to-convert-switch-to-raised-button-push-notifications) )

```
bool _enabled = false;

// [...]

RaisedButton(
      color: _enabled ? Colors.green : Colors.red,
      onPressed: () {
        setState(() {

        });
      },
      child: Text(_enabled? "On" : "Off")),
```

Enclosed a code that of course does not work , but should represent what I want so that it is easier to understand ..

```
RaisedButton(
      color: _light ? Colors.white : Colors.black,
      onPressed: () {
        setState(() {
           Magazin.of(context).setBrightness(Brightness.light);
           Magazin.of(context).setBrightness(Brightness.dark);
        });
      },
      child: Text(_light? "LIGHT THEME" : "DARK THEME")),
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: "SampleFont",
                              color: isDark ? Colors.green : Colors.red,
                              fontSize: 35.0,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this is you can use elevation property of raised button to make it a flat button.

```
child: RaisedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      isDark?Magazin.of(context).setBrightness(Brightness.light):Magazin.of(context).setBrightness(Brightness.dark);
                    },
                    elevation:isDark?0:2,//it will make it flat button for dark if you want it for light then replace 0 and 2
                    child: Text(isDark?'DARK MODE':'LIGHT MODE', style: TextStyle(color: isDark ? Colors.black : Colors.white, fontFamily: "SampleFont", fontSize: 13.0)),
                  ),
```

Comment: Perfect  works exactly as intended  Thank you very much for your help  

Answer (score 0):

You can create the buttons in separate functions and each time get your button from the correct one:

```
class _ToggledButtonsState extends State<ToggledButtons> {
  bool _isDark = false;

  FlatButton _getDarkButton() => FlatButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            _isDark = false;
          });
        },
        child: Text(
          'DARK MODE',
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
        ),
      );

  RaisedButton _getLightButton() => RaisedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            _isDark = true;
          });
        },
        child: Text(
          'LIGHT MODE',
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        ),
      );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: _isDark ? _getDarkButton() : _getLightButton(),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the most appropriate ways to do this is as follows:

```dart
abstract class MyTheme{
  Color get bgColor;
  Color get fontColor;
}

class MyLightTheme extends MyTheme{
  @override
  Color get bgColor = Colors.white;

  @override
  Color get fontColor = Colors.black;
}

class MyDarkTheme extends MyTheme{
  @override
  Color get bgColor = Colors.black;

  @override
  Color get fontColor = Colors.white;
}
```

ThemeService class:

```
// I use this with Provider. It is very helpful.
class ThemeService with ChangeNotifier{
  bool _theme;

  bool get theme => _theme;

  MyTheme _myTheme = MyLightTheme();

  MyTheme get myTheme => _myTheme;

  ThemeService.initialize() {
    init();
  }

  void setThemeClass(bool l) {
    _myTheme = MyLightTheme();
    if (l == false) _myTheme = MyLightTheme();
    else if (l == true) _myTheme = MyDarkTheme();
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future<void> init() async {
    SharedPreferences _prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    _theme = (_prefs.getBool("Theme") ?? false);
    setThemeClass(_theme);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void setTheme(bool l){
    setMyTheme(l);
  }

  Future<void> setMyTheme(bool l) async {
    SharedPreferences _prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    bool done = await _prefs.setBool("Theme", l);
    if (done) {
      _theme = l;
    }
    setThemeClass(_theme);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Provider code in the main.dart file:

```dart
MultiProvider(
  providers: [
    ChangeNotifierProvider<ThemeService>.value(
      value: ThemeService.initialize(),
    ),
  ],
  child: MyChild(),
}
```

Now, I can access the class in the following way:

```dart
ThemeService _themeService = Provider.of<ThemeService>(context);
// Now, for background color, I'll just use the following:
_themeService.bgColor;
// Above code will give me the background color based on the currently selected theme.
```

Code for switch:

```dart
ThemeService _themeService = Provider.of<ThemeService>(context);

Switch(  
  onChanged: setTheme,
  value: _themeService.theme,
)
```